# Redirect based on subdomain

Tags: apache

I want to redirect a.example.com to a.example.com/a, b.example.com to b.example.com/b etc. I have tried to add the following to my VHost:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.example\.com
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/%1
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1.example.com/%1/%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NC,QSA]
```

But I get:
"This webpage has a redirect loop"

I don't get why this happens, as the second rewrite condition is meant to stop rewriting if the beginning of the `REQUEST_URI` matches the subdomain.

Comment: Activate the rewrite log, then you can find out exactly what’s going on.

Comment: Thanks. The request url doesn't seem to match the subdomain backreference hence the redirection loop. However, I don't know how I can solve this